# Default retention.ms failed to create internal change log topic for selectKey()

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

We use selectKey() to change the key. It works well before we move to a new standard plan event stream on IBM Cloud. Then we caught exception below. It said our topic retentions.ms did not fit to range [3600000..2592000000]. So I was wondering how could we fix this problem.

Thanks,

```
[WARNING]
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Could not create topic employeeFilter-KSTREAM-KEY-SELECT-0000000047-repartition.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopicManager.makeReady(InternalTopicManager.java:138)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor.prepareTopic(StreamsPartitionAssignor.java:892)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor.assign(StreamsPartitionAssignor.java:472)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.performAssignment(ConsumerCoordinator.java:419)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.onJoinLeader(AbstractCoordinator.java:592)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.access$1100(AbstractCoordinator.java:94)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$JoinGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:544)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$JoinGroupResponseHandler.handle(AbstractCoordinator.java:527)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:894)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator$CoordinatorResponseHandler.onSuccess(AbstractCoordinator.java:874)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture$1.onSuccess(RequestFuture.java:204)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.fireSuccess(RequestFuture.java:167)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.RequestFuture.complete(RequestFuture.java:127)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler.fireCompletion(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:586)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.firePendingCompletedRequests(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:400)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:303)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:242)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:218)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:413)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:352)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:337)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:343)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1218)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1175)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1154)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:861)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:810)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:767)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:736)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.PolicyViolationException: Invalid retention.ms specified. The allowed range is [3600000..2592000000]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.get(KafkaFutureImpl.java:262)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopicManager.makeReady(InternalTopicManager.java:122)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.PolicyViolationException: Invalid retention.ms specified. The allowed range is [3600000..2592000000]
11:40:52.647 [main] INFO  com.ibm.hr.mobility.processor.EmployeeProcessorApplication - Started EmployeeProcessorApplication in 944.09 seconds (JVM running for 954.418)
```

Comment: You should include the code of your application. Otherwise it is difficult to help you.

Answer (score 1):

> The allowed range is [3600000..2592000000]

Your broker only allows creating topics with a retention of 1 hour to 30 days and it appears that you are trying to create a topic with a retention outside that range.

Comment: Kafka Streams creates repartition topics with infinite retention time. Compare: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6535